# Expo with socket.io websocket failing to connect

Tags: javascript, react-native, socket.io, expo

I am attempting to connect to a socket.io server from within an Expo app. I am having issues being able to connect to my server. I have a web app that connect to the server fine, so the server is working OK. I have also looked at some examples, including one from the Expo repo, to no avail.

My client:

```
componentDidMount() {

    const socket = socketIOClient('http://192.168.1.210:80', {
      transports: ['websocket']
    });

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected.');
    });

    socket.on('connect_error', (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Server:

```
this.httpServer = HttpServer.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end('');
});

this.httpServer.listen(80);

this.io = new IOServer({
  pingInterval: 10000,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
});

this.io.listen(this.httpServer);
this.io.set('transports', ['websocket']);

this.onConnection();

this.io.on('connection', (socket) => {/* events */}
```

The on connect event will never fire, only the connect_error event which simply says 'timeout'. Native websockets work fine when testing against https://www.websocket.org/echo.html.

Comment: I've heard of someone who also has problems with socket.io. Enabling remote debugging made it work for him. He has no clue why though.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug with socket.io to do with loading in the incorrect `WebSocket` implementation.

It was looking for `self.WebSocket`, but `self` does not exist in React Native, so it was falling back to `require('ws')`, the Node.js implementation. In reality, it should have been using the native `WebSocket` implementation in React Native.

I've made a PR to solve this: https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client/pull/607

The reason that turning on remote debugging makes it work is since the code runs in a browser (Chrome) in this mode, it's able to use the browser's `WebSocket` implementation.